# How to Join a Variant()?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to use `Join()` to get a string from a `Range`.

```
s = Range("a1:a3")
[b2] = TypeName(s)
[b3] = Join(s)
```

This throws `Run-time Error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument` on the third line.

The `Typename` of the range is `Variant()`, but when I try with `s=Array(1,2,3)`, the typename is the same, but it works.

I got it to work with

```
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(s)
```

but I would like to know why `Join()` fails.

Answer (score 3):

If you assign a multiple cell range value to a variable, you get a 2D array, which won't work with `Join`. Since it's a vertical range you could use:

```
Join(Application.Transpose(s))
```

for a horizontal range, you'd need to transpose twice.

Comment: You should note that `Application.Transpose` has a limit of about 2^16 elements, after which it begins giving flaky results.  Not a problem with the example given by the OP, but could be an issue for others looking at this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use the Range directly rather than the array derived from the Range:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim s As Range
    Set s = Range("a1:a3")
    [b2] = TypeName(s)
    [b3] = Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin("", False, s)
End Sub
```

This avoids using `Transpose()`